# How to convert Date format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Basically I want to convert date format from 'yyyy-mm-dd' to 'mm/dd/yyyy'.

Now here is the thing :

I used this to select current date.

```
Select GetDate();
```

Which  shows the format as : 2015-07-10 14:29:30.227
Then :

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101)
```

It is working and displaying the result as : 07/10/2015

Now when I try to do this:

```
Select CONVERT(DATE, CAST('2015-06-15' AS DATE), 101)
```

And it does not show the desired result. Instead it shows the same format as : 2015-06-15

Any suggesstion would be of great help!!

Comment: the `101` is what drives the format.

Comment: yes, why is it working when using getdate but not when i use a date

Comment: Select CONVERT(Varchar(10), CAST('2015-06-15' AS DATE), 101)

Comment: @MelgoV You might as well post that as an answer - I was about to but you beat me to it in a comment.

Comment: yep, it worked, so the probelm lies in the syntax 'CAST AS DATE'

Comment: no the problem lies in the syntax `CONVERT(DATE`  it's already a date

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Select CONVERT(Varchar(10), CAST('2015-06-15' AS DATE), 101)
```